# How to elongate down arrow?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

`\downarrow` command is available in directory but it has fixed length. How can I elongate its length?

[image]

Answer (score 58):

The `\downarrow` symbol is an extensible delimiter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\xdownarrow}[1]{%
  {\left\downarrow\vbox to #1{}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
}

\begin{document}

$
\downarrow
\big\downarrow
\Big\downarrow
\bigg\downarrow
\Bigg\downarrow
\xdownarrow{2cm}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use the same method also for `\uparrow`, `\updownarrow`, `\Downarrow`, `\Uparrow` and `\Updownarrow`.

Comment: Your arrow isn't 2cm height. Its total height is approximately 2*(2cm-A), where A is math axis height.

Comment: @wipet Did I say it is? But thanks for noting, it can help readers.

Comment: [Looking at the tip](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kIbtS.png) it seems as if the unscaled and scaled arrows are different glyphs.

Comment: @HenriMenke Correct.

Answer (score 8):

You can define your own command, for example:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\xdownarrow[1][2ex]{%
   \mathrel{\rotatebox{90}{$\xleftarrow{\rule{#1}{0pt}}$}}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\xdownarrow\quad
\xdownarrow[30pt]\quad
\xdownarrow[2.5cm]
\]

\end{document}
```

The default length is `2ex` and you can control it using the optional argument for `\xdownarrow`.

With the above definition, the arrow tip will sit on the baseline, you can change the definition to

```
\newcommand\xdownarrow[1][2ex]{%
   \mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\xleftarrow{\rule{#1}{0pt}}$}}
}
```

for a vertically centered symbol.

Comment: `\rotatebox`? Really? `;-)`

Answer (score 6):

You can also draw it with `tikz` which gives you a lot of flexibility should you desire any customization such as arrow styles, colors, and line styles:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}% So that we can have two optional parameters

\NewDocumentCommand\DownArrow{O{2.0ex} O{black}}{%
   \mathrel{\tikz[baseline] \draw [<-, line width=0.5pt, #2] (0,0) -- ++(0,#1);}
}

\begin{document}

\[ a
\DownArrow b 
\DownArrow[30pt][>=latex,red, ultra thick] c
\DownArrow[2.5cm][>=stealth,blue, thick, dashed] b
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A (similar) alternative, using *gathered* environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xdownarrow}[2][]{%
\left.{#1}\right\downarrow{#2}}

\begin{document}

$
\xdownarrow[\begin{gathered}
    \vspace{5cm}
    \end{gathered}]{}
$

\end{document}
```

If you want, it can be used with linebreaks inside:

```
$
\xdownarrow[\begin{gathered}
    \\
    \\
    \\
    \end{gathered}]{}
$
```

Usually I use this scheme to place a specific down-arrow across multirows in a table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\xdownarrow}[2][]{%
\left.{#1}\right\downarrow{#2}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
  {Lower}   & Text 1\\
  \multirow{2}{*}{$\xdownarrow[\begin{gathered}
  \hfill \\
  \hfill \\
  \hfill \\
  \end{gathered}]{}$ }
            & Text 2\\
            & Text 3\\
            & Text 4\\
            & Text 5\\
  {Higher}  & Text 6\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]