# Drawing a vertical line between labels and items when using enumitem

Tags: enumitem

I am using the description environment of the enumitem package. I want to draw a long vertical line between the labels and the items. For instance, the result would be like

[image]

This example is drawn by using the tabularx package, which is not quite convenient for this use. The code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\prol}{\textsf{PL}}
\newcommand{\fol}{\textsf{FOL}}
\newcommand{\wff}{\textsf{wff}}
\newcommand{\ltrue}{\textsf{T}}
\newcommand{\lfalse}{\textsf{F}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r|X}
Sentence & A sentence (also closed formula or ground formula) in logic refer to a declarative sentence that is either \ltrue{} or \lfalse{}. In \prol{}, 1) an atomic sentence have multiple constants and a single predicate; and 2) a compound sentence is formed by multiple atomic sentences combined by truth-functional connectives. In \fol{}, a sentence is a \wff{} with no free variables. A sentence can be viewed as expressing a proposition, something that must be \ltrue{} or \lfalse{}. The restriction of having no free variables is needed to make sure that sentences can have concrete, fixed truth values. An atomic sentence is a sentence that has two or more logical subjects (constants) and a single predicate.\\

Claim & = Proposition\\

Proposition & A proposition is a particular kind of declarative sentence that affirms or denies a predicate of a subject. A proposition is either \ltrue{} or \lfalse{}.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The line must persist on page change. I could not find a built-in function related to this in the user manual.

Comment: By use of `tikzmark` library or package. As an example of its use see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520483/. You only need to provide enough room between items and their labels. For further help please provide an example of your list.

Comment: You could adapt the technique shown here that draws a box, to only draw the line [Box around a few items in an itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45926/4301).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikZ}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\prol}{\textsf{PL}}
\newcommand{\fol}{\textsf{FOL}}
\newcommand{\wff}{\textsf{wff}}
\newcommand{\ltrue}{\textsf{T}}
\newcommand{\lfalse}{\textsf{F}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}[align=right, labelsep=2em, leftmargin=\labelsep]
\item[Sentence] 
    \tikzmarknode{A}{A} sentence (also closed formula or ground formula) in logic refer to a declarative sentence  that is either \ltrue{} or \lfalse{}. In \prol{}, 1) an atomic sentence have multiple  constants and a single predicate; and 2) a compound sentence is formed by multiple atomic  sentences combined by truth-functional connectives. In \fol{}, a sentence is a \wff{} with no free variables. A sentence can be viewed as expressing a proposition, something that must be \ltrue{} or \lfalse{}. The restriction of having no free variables is needed to make sure that sentences can have concrete, fixed truth values. An atomic sentence is a sentence that has two or more logical subjects (constants) and a single predicate.

\item[Claim]
    = Proposition

\item[Proposition]
    A proposition is a particular kind of declarative sentence that affirms or denies a predicate of a subject. A proposition is either \ltrue{} or \tikzmarknode{B}{\lfalse{}}.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
                        ]
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-1em}] (A.north west) -- (A.west |- B.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

After (at least) two compilation you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems it is hard to make a new environment for this.

Comment: @Hermis14, oh, it is not so hard, if you have some overview of `tikz` package possibilities :-). Or simple ask here ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to make a more general environment using newenvironment? I mean, it seems that `tikzmarknode` has to be placed inside the item text, which makes it impossible to make a good environment; it is possible, but the environment structure might probably look complicated due to required arguments.