# Describe part of equation with arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations

I want to add additional annotations to parts of equations using tikz.
Using some examples I found, I came up with the following approach.
Where a tikzmkark is placed inside of the equation and used later to draw an arrow to a text description:

```
   \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,positioning}
    \newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}

    \begin{document}
      \begin{equation*}
          a = \tikzmark{log}{$\log(b)$} + 3
      \end{equation*}

      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =.5cm]
          \node (logdescr) [below=of log]{Description};
          \draw[,->,thick] (log) to [in=90,out=-90] (logdescr);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Unfortunately, somehow the spacing of the equation gets broken when I use $$ inside of the tikzmark command.
As shown as below:

[image: example output]

Comment: Use the `\tikzmark` command of the `tikzmark` library. That is, add `tikzmark` to the loaded libraries, `\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,positioning,tikzmark}`, and remove `\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}`. The reason why it fails is that the latter has an `overlay` in. Also, use `a = \tikzmark{log}{\log(b)} + 3` then.

Answer (score 1):

Here I added two variants of code `LaTeX` for the size of the word **Description**.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\newcommand{\xdownarrow}[1]{%
  {\left\downarrow\vbox to #1{}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
} % @egreg macro https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213811/how-to-elongate-down-arrow


\begin{document}
\[\underset{\substack{\Big\downarrow\\\text{Description}}}{a=\log(b)+3}\]

\[\underset{\substack{\Big\downarrow\\\text{\large Description}}}{a=\log(b)+3}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the problem you report? Because you have an `overlay` in

```
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[3][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base,#1](#2) {#3};}
```

But there is no need to use this command, use `\tikzmarknode` from the beautiful `tikzmark` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
 a = \tikzmarknode{log}{\log(b)} + 3
\end{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,node distance =.5cm]
    \node (logdescr) [below=of log]{Description};
    \draw[,->,thick] (log) to [in=90,out=-90] (logdescr);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```