# How can one increase the width of an arrow?

Tags: arrows

A previous post "How to elongate down arrow?"([How to elongate down arrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213811/how-to-elongate-down-arrow)) tells us how to increase the length of the arrow. As a next step, how can one increase the width of the arrow?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should be more specific. How is produced this arrow? As part f some (math) font or it can be drawn for example by Ti*k*Z?

Comment: You may check for TikZ, pgfmanual, there you'll find lots of arrows and hints for  customization.

Comment: To build on https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=GIM...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you linked in your comment (by the way, do not link code but put it in your question):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        line width=3pt,
    }
}

\newcommand{\arrowup}{%
\tikz[baseline=12pt]{\draw [->, myarrow] (0,0) -- ++(0,20pt);}
}
\newcommand{\arrowdown}{%
\tikz[baseline=12pt]{\draw [<-, myarrow] (0,0) -- ++(0,20pt);}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
This is some text.\linebreak
\arrowdown\linebreak
And some more.\linebreak
\arrowup\linebreak
And even more.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]